# Resque worker not responding to signals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, resque, worker

I'm using version 1.25.2 of Resque in a Rails app.

I tried to invoke the instance methods `pause_processing` and its reverse `unpause_processing` of `Resque::Worker` class on all the workers I fetched through `Resque.workers`. However the workers still continued to process new jobs added dynamically to any queue. When checked for the state through `instance.paused?` every worker returned `true`.

Not sure if I can really control the workers running in background.

As far as I can comprehend `pause_processing`,`unpause_processing` and `shutdown` do the same thing as sending `USR2` `CONT` and `KILL` signals to Resque workers.

Am I missing something trivial or is there another way to manage the workers.

Comment: Can anyone atleast point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you're calling this method and modifying state on an entirely different instance of the worker. As you [can see](https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/1-x-stable/lib/resque/worker.rb#L484) all it does is set the value of an instance variable. When you call `Resque.workers`, you get instances of all the workers—but not the instance of the running worker in a different process. Resque doesn't allow you to modify the state of a running worker remotely. You must interact with it by signals if you want to change the state of a Resque worker from the outside. If you're just calling the methods, you're not sending a signal.